# What's the difference between “by night” and “at night”?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, at-by

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/by?q=by) say ***by*** has the meaning of

> **6.** indicating the period in which something happens: ‘this animal always hunts by night’

Then do we need to say, ‘Why does the sky glitter **by** night?’ And can’t we say, ‘Why does the sky glitter **at** night?’?

If we can use both, what’s the difference between the two?

Comment: A photo of  Paris can have the subtitle "Paris by night" or "Paris at night" , there is no difference.

Comment: @rogermue No difference at the denotational level. I know which one _I_'d be more predisposed to buy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression `by night` is typically used to contrast someone's nighttime activities to their daytime activities, especially when the nighttime activities are unusual or unexpected. You will see it very frequently in the construction `X by day, Y by night`. Some examples:

> - ...treated it like a greasy spoon by day and a hotel by night
> - I mean, if it's -- if it's somebody that is -- is living as a man that's a woman or living as a woman that's a man or someone that's a prostitute by night and a -- and a secretary or a lawyer by day.
> - He's a DJ by night, a graphic artist by day. He's multifaceted.
> - ...he dwelled, chief of all worldly American expats, hanging out with bullfighters, jai alai players, and ex-Spanish Loyalist guerrillas, awash in drink and worldly women, fishing by day, partying by night, writing the whole time.

On the other hand, `at night` is much less constrained as to the interpretation. The preferred thing to say will be that the `sky glitters at night`, since this is the expected activity for a sky. To say that an animal `hunts by night` uses the `by night` expression because we normally think of day time as the time where animals should be most active, based on our own experience.

Another useful note is that `by night` can almost always be replaced by `at night` without altering the acceptability of the sentence, but not vice versa.

Comment: Interesting. Makes one wonder why there is no "at day".

Comment: This is a longshot, but have you any sources explaining how this sense of 'by' arose?

Comment: "Paris by night"?

Answer (score 4):

I would put the difference down to more of a sense of drama with use of *by*. "The tiger hunts by night" sounds more dramatic than "The tiger hunts at night."

Consider the title of the following film: [They Drive by Night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Drive_By_Night), which is a hyped-up way of presenting a movie about truck drivers who are trying to survive in their tough world. Had the film been called "They Drive at Night" it would have sounded pretty ho-hum.

Comment: There's hardly anything "dramatic" about the subject matter in saying someone [sleeps by day](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sleeps+by+day%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Personally I think its an exotic/quaint [but declining](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sleeps+by+day%2Cworks+by+night&year_start=1840&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) Victorianism. It's usually ***at** night* today, but I don't know why there's no such direct replacement for *by day*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The time of day the OP was interested in is night, not day. As for the dramatic, I think you expect that term to mean something more exalted or ponderous than I intend here. Remeber, I said *more* dramatic; that shouldn't take you all the way to *The Women of Try* or *MacBeth*, merely to a '30s movie about truckers. Sheesh.

Comment: What I meant was there's nothing *inherently* "dramatic" about using *by* rather than *at*. It only has those associations because it's an archaic/poetic form. Plus there are doubtless still millions of kids dutifully learning to sing [*while shepherds washed their socks **by** night*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL9HG9oL2wQ), which all adds to the general sense of "this is a *special* usage".

Comment: Obviously I meant *The Women of Troy*. Stupid keyboard. Stupid fingers.

Comment: I'm still trying to work out whether your capitalisation of *MacBeth* is some subtlety that passes me by (not unlikely, as I fully accept! :). Though I do find it intriguing that you can do things *at night*, but not *at day*. And if you do anything ***by** day*, it's almost invariably by way of contrast with something different that you do *by night*, as @jlovegren points out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I typed that when tired. Obviously I mean *Macbeth*. Just like I meant *Troy* instead of *Try*. Too bad you can't edit comments after the grace period.